# iBeacon to push another view! iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon, beacon

What I am trying to do is make it so that when an iBeacon has been found (when the user is on the home screen), it sends them to another part of the app. Essentially it pushes another view of the app from the storyboard. For example, iBeacon1 pushes View1, iBeacon2 pushes View2, etc, and that's it. Like I said I know that it possible, but because iBeacons are quite new, there isn't much help available.

I would really appreciate it if you could take some time out of your day to help me with this issue that I cannot find the answer to.

Thank you for your time,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Storyboards, you could do something like this in your `AppDelegate`:

```
var launchedViewControllers = [Int]()

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {
  let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  if let navController = self.window?.rootViewController?.navigationController {
    for beacon in beacons {
      if (beacon.minor == 1) {
        if !launchedViewControllers.contains(beacon.minor.integerValue) {
          launchedViewControllers.append(beacon.minor.integerValue)
          let viewController1 = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewController1")
          navController.pushViewController(viewController1, animated: true)
        }
      }
      if (beacon.minor == 2) {
        if !launchedViewControllers.contains(beacon.minor.integerValue) {
          launchedViewControllers.append(beacon.minor.integerValue)
          let viewController2 = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewController1")
          navController.pushViewController(viewController2, animated: true)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could also rewrite this to use segues instead of programmatically pushing `ViewControllers` using a `NavigationController` but both will work.

Comment: Might also be a good idea to immediately stop ranging after pushing a new view controller onto the navigation stack (:

Comment: I think the questioner wants to keep ranging so if a different beacon comes into view, a different view controller is launched.  That is why my proposed solution has flags for whether the view controllers have already been launched (to prevent repeat launches.)

Answer (score 0):

## pragma mark -

## pragma mark -Important Methods

-(void)showSecondController{

```
if ([_beacon.major isEqual: @3404] && [_beacon.minor isEqual: @10692]) {
    
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait] forKey:@"orientation"];
    
    self.secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SDOVideoDetailController"];
    
} else if ([_beacon.major isEqual: @20165] && [_beacon.minor isEqual: @53849]) {
    
    
    
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))
        
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait] forKey:@"orientation"];
    
    
    
    self.secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LRCVideoDetailController"];
    
}  else if ([_beacon.major isEqual: @53088] && [_beacon.minor isEqual: @30487]) {
    
    
    
    
    
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))
        
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait] forKey:@"orientation"];
    
    
    
    self.secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CECSVideoDetailController"];
    
    
    
}  else if ([_beacon.major isEqual: @55304] && [_beacon.minor isEqual: @59835]) {
    
    
    
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))
        
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait] forKey:@"orientation"];
    
    
    
    self.secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IVideoDetailController"];
    
}  else if ([_beacon.major isEqual: @16004] && [_beacon.minor isEqual: @46054]) {
    
    
    
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))
        
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait] forKey:@"orientation"];
    
    
    
    self.secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CILVideoDetailController"];
    
}  else if ([_beacon.major isEqual: @20214] && [_beacon.minor isEqual: @11696]) {
    
    
    
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))
        
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait] forKey:@"orientation"];
    
    
    
    self.secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ITVideoDetailController"];
    
}  else if ([_beacon.major isEqual: @21559] && [_beacon.minor isEqual: @17557]) {
    
    
    
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))
        
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait] forKey:@"orientation"];
    
    
    
    self.secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PARKVideoDetailController"];
    
}  else if ([_beacon.major isEqual: @59452] && [_beacon.minor isEqual: @21013]) {
    
    
    
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))
        
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait] forKey:@"orientation"];
    
    
    
    self.secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SCVideoDetailController"];
    
}  else if ([_beacon.major isEqual: @42093] && [_beacon.minor isEqual: @49773]) {
    
    
    
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))
        
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait] forKey:@"orientation"];
    
    
    
    self.secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BAVideoDetailController"];
    
}
```